# Is it possible to create an instrumental version of an mp3 file in Mathematica?

Tags: import, sound

I'm aware that it's possible to use a program like Audacity to do this and that it's most likely easier, but I'd like to know how to make instrumental versions of songs in the mp3 format using Mathematica.

I'm starting with practically no knowledge of sound data and therefore have no starting point other than importing the file.

Is this possible and how might I go about it?

Comment: Do you have a sample MP3 we can test things on?

Comment: Can you tackle the non-Mathematica part first? Do you have any methods in mind that can potentially remove the human voice?  Then we can discuss implementing those methods in Mathematica.